# Парсинг XML файла два одинаковых тэга

Tags: python, xml

Ребята помогите пожалуйста!
Есть некий xml файл:

`<SwiftTest><Data type="BinaryCustomStatisticsDocument" version="1" Type="Line">
    <Series StatString="load.scenarios.attempts" AutoColorCode="False" Axis="Count" Color="4278190335" DefaultIsVisible="True" DefaultShowLabels="False" DefaultShowPoints="False">
    <Flag Name="Load">0x0001</Flag>
    <Flag Name="Total/Per Second">0x0001</Flag></Series>`

Вот в чём проблема.
Мне нужно извлечь из тэга  только Total/Per Second
Я к сожалению смог только извлечь вот таким методом:

`for v in tree.iter(tag='Flag'):
        values = v.attrib['Name']`

И он извлекает вот так:

`Load
Total/Per Second`

пользуюсь xml.etree.ElementTree

Comment: Ну с помощью какой магии вы хотите что бы возращался какой-то конкретный тег? У вас есть список оданиковых ключей, вы и  получаете список ключей...

Comment: `tree.find("Flag[@Name='Total/Per Second']")`

Comment: Большое спасибо!работает.